# Converting a ComboBox to an AutoCompleteBox using the WPF Toolkit

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpftoolkit, autocompletebox

I'm having a bit of trouble to achieve the conversion of a "complex" ComboBox to an equally complex AutoCompleteBox. My goal is to be able to select and set a ShoppingCart's Item to be like one of the Items of a list. Here's the three steps to take to reproduce my situation *(I'm using Stylet and its SetAndNotify() INPC method)*:

1. Create two objects, one having only a Name property and the other one having only the other object as a property

   ```
   public class ItemModel : PropertyChangedBase
   {
       private string _name;
       public string Name
       {
           get => _name;
           set => SetAndNotify(ref _name, value);
       }
   }

   public class ShoppingCartModel : PropertyChangedBase
   {
       public ItemModel Item { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. initialize and Populate both the ItemsList and the Shoppingcart in the DataContext *(since we're using MVVM, it's the ViewModel)*

   ```
   public ShoppingCartModel ShoppingCart { get; set; }
   public ObservableCollection<ItemModel> ItemsList { get; set; }

   public ShellViewModel()
   {
       ItemsList = new ObservableCollection<ItemModel>()
       {
           new ItemModel { Name = "T-shirt"},
           new ItemModel { Name = "Jean"},
           new ItemModel { Name = "Boots"},
           new ItemModel { Name = "Hat"},
           new ItemModel { Name = "Jacket"},
       };

       ShoppingCart = new ShoppingCartModel() { Item = new ItemModel() };
   }
   ```
3. Create the AutoCompleteBox, ComboBox, and a small TextBlock inside the View to test it all out:

   ```
   <Window [...] xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=DotNetProjects.Input.Toolkit">

       <!-- Required Template to show the names of the Items in the ItemsList -->
       <Window.Resources>
           <DataTemplate x:Key="AutoCompleteBoxItemTemplate">
               <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent">
                   <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
               </StackPanel>
           </DataTemplate>
       </Window.Resources>

       <StackPanel>
           <!-- AutoCompleteBox: can see the items list but selecting doesn't change ShoppingCart.Item.Name -->
           <Label Content="AutoCompleteBox with ShoppingCart.Item.Name as SelectedItem:"/>
           <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsList}"
                                    ValueMemberPath="Name"
                                    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=ShoppingCart.Item.Name}" 
                                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AutoCompleteBoxItemTemplate}"/>

           <!-- ComboBox: can see the items list and selecting changes ShoppingCart.Item.Name value -->
           <Label Content="ComboBox with ShoppingCart.Item.Name as SelectedValue:"/>
           <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsList}" 
                     DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                     SelectedValue="{Binding Path=ShoppingCart.Item.Name}"
                     SelectedValuePath="Name"
                     SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=ShoppingCart.Item}" />

           <!-- TextBox: Typing "Jean" or "Jacket" updates the ComboBox, but not the AutoCompleteBox -->
           <Label Content="Value of ShoppingCart.Item.Name:"/>
           <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=ShoppingCart.Item.Name}"/>
       </StackPanel>
   </window>
   ```

Changing the Binding Mode of the AutoCompleteBox's SelectedItem to TwoWay makes it print "**[ProjectName].ItemModel**" which means *(I guess?)* it's getting ItemModels and not strings, but I can't seem to make it work. Any help will be appreciated, thanks and feel free to edit my post if it's possible to make it smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of attempts, I finally found the culprits :

- INPC not implemented in `ShoppingCartModel.Item` despite the `PropertyChangedBase` inheritance *(either implementing INPC or remove the `PropertyChangedBase` inheritance work)*

  ```
  public class ShoppingCartModel : PropertyChangedBase
  {
      private ItemModel _item;
      public ItemModel Item
      {
          get => _item;
          set => SetAndNotify(ref _item, value);
      }
  }
  ```
- AutoCompleteBox's `SelectedItem` must be of the same type of `ItemsSource`, and have a `TwoWay` Mode `Binding`

  ```
  <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsList}"
                           ValueMemberPath="Name"
                           SelectedItem="{Binding Path=ShoppingCart.Item, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                           ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AutoCompleteBoxItemTemplate}"/>
  ```
- And finally... the most mysterious one is the ComboBox! Simply by being there it messes with the `AutoCompleteBox` and I have no idea why, just commenting the whole ComboBox makes it all work. If you know why the ComboBox breaks the AutoCompleteBox's binding feel free to help.

  [image: AutoCompleteBox working]

There's another problem though, when using an AutoCompleteBox inside a ListView, but [it's better to create a separate question for that issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63524395/wpftoolkit-autocompletebox-not-binding-correctly-inside-listview)