# WPFToolkit AutoCompleteBox not binding correctly inside ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpftoolkit

[After struggling a bit to just get started with WPFToolkit's AutoCompleteBox control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63442398/converting-a-combobox-to-an-autocompletebox-using-the-wpf-toolkit), I'm facing another issue when trying to use an **AutoCompleteBox inside a ListView**, it almost binds perfectly but for a reason I ignore it doesn't show at first the `ValueMemberPath` and instead tries to convert the object to string which gives `Namespace.object` instead of the proper `ValueMemberPath` value, however when selecting another item in the AutoCompleteBox it works perfectly and it doesn't show any other `Namespace.object`.

[image] [image]

Here's my code, you can just copy and paste it to get the same result *(don't forget to add* `DotNetProjects.WpfToolkit.Input` *in NuGet Package Manager)* :

- Namespace.MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Namespace.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Namespace"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=DotNetProjects.Input.Toolkit"
        Title="AutoCompleteBox in ListView" Height="300" Width="350" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    
    <!-- Required Template to show the names of the Items in the ItemsList -->
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="AutoCompleteBoxItemTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent">
                <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    
    <StackPanel Margin="5">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0 5 0 0">
            <StackPanel Width="{Binding ElementName=FirstColumnWidth, Path=ActualWidth}">
                <TextBlock Text="ACB binded to Cart.Item"/>
                
                <!-- ACB that binds correctly -->
                <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox 
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemsList}"
                                   ValueMemberPath="Name"
                                   SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Cart.Item, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                   ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AutoCompleteBoxItemTemplate}"/>
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Margin="15 0 0 0">
                <TextBlock Text="Value of Cart.Item.Name"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Cart.Item.Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>

        <TextBlock Margin="0 30 0 0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="ListView with CartsList as ItemsListSource"/>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding CartsList}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="FirstColumnWidth">
                        <GridViewColumn.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="ACB binded to each Cart.Item"/>
                        </GridViewColumn.Header>
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <!-- ACB that doesn't bind correctly -->
                                <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox
                                  ItemsSource="{
                                        Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window},
                                        Path=DataContext.ItemsList}"
                                   ValueMemberPath="Name"
                                   SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Item, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                   ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AutoCompleteBoxItemTemplate}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>

                    <GridViewColumn >
                        <GridViewColumn.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="Value of each Cart.Item.Name"/>
                        </GridViewColumn.Header>
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Item.Name}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

- Code-Behind (MainWindow.xaml.cs)

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;

namespace Namespace
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        // INPC Implementation
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        // The list that contains Items that will be chosen in a Cart
        private ObservableCollection<Item> _ItemsList;
        public ObservableCollection<Item> ItemsList
        {
            get => _ItemsList;
            set
            {
                _ItemsList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        // The list that contains Carts that will be shown in the ListView
        private ObservableCollection<Cart> _CartsList;
        public ObservableCollection<Cart> CartsList
        {
            get => _CartsList;
            set
            {
                _CartsList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        // A signle Cart
        private Cart _Cart;
        public Cart Cart
        {
            get => _Cart;
            set
            {
                _Cart = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            DataContext = this;
            InitializeComponent();

            // Populating ItemsList
            ItemsList = new ObservableCollection<Item>()
            {
                new Item("T-shirt"), new Item("Jeans"), new Item("Boots"),
            };

            // Populating CartsList
            CartsList = new ObservableCollection<Cart>()
            {
                new Cart(ItemsList[0]),
                new Cart(ItemsList[2]),
                new Cart(ItemsList[1]),
                new Cart(ItemsList[0]),
                new Cart(ItemsList[1]),
            };

            // Setting an Item to Cart
            Cart = new Cart(ItemsList[2]);

        }
    }

    // Cart Object
    public class Cart
    {
        public Item Item { get; set; }

        public Cart(Item item) => Item = item;
    }

    // Item Object
    public class Item
    {
        // Important to be private set so it cannot be changed
        public string Name { get; private set; }

        public Item(string name) => Name = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the selection change that updates the text according to the `ValueMemberPath` is not triggered when nesting the `AutoCompleteBox` in the `ListView`. The `SelectionChanged` event does not even fire. I could not figure out why exactly and if this is a bug or not. However,  I can show you a **workaround** using the [`Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf/) package.

You can create a trigger action that resets the `SelectedItem` and assigns it again on `AutoCompleteBox`.

```
public class ForceUpdateSelectedItemAction : TriggerAction<AutoCompleteBox>
{
   protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
   {
      var selectedItem = AssociatedObject.SelectedItem;
      AssociatedObject.SetCurrentValue(AutoCompleteBox.SelectedItemProperty, null);
      AssociatedObject.SetCurrentValue(AutoCompleteBox.SelectedItemProperty, selectedItem);
   }
}
```

This trigger action can be used for the `Loaded` event of the `AutoCompleteBox`.

```
<toolkit:AutoCompleteBox ...>
   <b:Interaction.Triggers>
      <b:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
         <local:ForceUpdateSelectedItemAction/>
      </b:EventTrigger>
   </b:Interaction.Triggers>
</toolkit:AutoCompleteBox>
```

This will cause an update of the selection and the text without changing the bound property.

Comment: It does the trick! I wasn't sure if it was a bug or not but now it's all clear thanks to you. I created a new issue on the fork's github page to report the bug here: https://github.com/dotnetprojects/WpfToolkit/issues/46